# Skydrive is constantly syncing showing processing changes

Tags: onedrive

All documents and folders show the "Green checkmark" icon indicating that they have been sync'd but the skydrive icon in the system tray still shows that it's "processing changes"

Unlinking/relinking Skydrive doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 6):

I solved my Windows 10 Onedrive constantly showing "Processing changes". It was caused by some of the folders having incorrect user permissions. I had to go to folder security settings, advanced, and ensure that my user name had full control of each folder+subfolders and files.

Comment: This was the issue for me as well.  In my case the permissions somehow got so screwed up that I couldn't easily fix them; I ended up using icacls as described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/22453562/199172 to reset the entire offline OneDrive folder.  After that, ta da!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, moving file/ folder (which doesn't seem to be syncing) to another location within the SkyDrive folder also works.

Unlinking is not possible in Windows 8 if you're using Windows with a Microsoft account.

Answer (score 1):

on the skydrive server (https://skydrive.live.com) the .lock file got sync'd and had to be deleted from the server.

1. Unlink skydrive from the PC
2. logon to https://skydrive.live.com) and delete the .lock file
3. relink skydrive to the PC

Comment: I have the same problem as above but a search and manual inspection of the skydrive folder does not show any lock files.

Answer (score 1):

﻿Found a solution to the "processing change" issue

I had the continuous processing changes issue on my Windows 7 Ultimate X64 computer with OneDrive and OneDrive for Business and I found a solution that worked for me. I discovered that turning off UAC would correct the problem, but I wanted to leave UAC enabled, so I went to Programs, righted clicked on the OneDrive and left clicked on Properties. Then opened compatibility and selected Server 2008 SP2 and clicked apply and OneDrive started syncing without any issues. You cannot run OneDrive for Business in compatibility mode, but to my surprise, after changing OneDrive to compatibility mode, the issues were corrected in OneDrive for Business. If you are not aware of the difference OneDrive is the personal cloud storage linked and outlook.com account and OneDrive for Business is cloud storage linked to an Office365 account.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue a couple times now. Both times I've strangely fixed it by running a Repair on MS Office in Add/Delete Programs on Windows 7 in the control panel. I have Office 365 that likes to link stuff to OneDrive/SkyDrive so there may be an issue there. Never the less it may be worth a shot if you have this or other MS Office products installed.

Answer (score 1):

Reset your OneDrive
    `%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\onedrive.exe /reset`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, on both my personal OneDrive and work OneDrive account. Changing the ownership of my OneDrive folder to my Microsoft account fixed immediately the issue I had with my personal one. I had to unlink the work OneDrive account and re-setup. That fixed the work OneDrive account.

Both are working well now.